# Python Dask max() function on a column not working

Tags: python, dask

The max() for Dask on a column does not work.  The below code returns with the result.  Could anyone help to advise how to get the max() of a column in Dask dataframe?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import dask.bag as db

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Last Name': ['Johnson', 'Cameron', 'Biden', 'Washington'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18], 'Weight': [60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0]})  
print('pandas_df is')
print(pandas_df)  

print('max Age from Pandas Dataframe is')
print(str(pandas_df['Age'].max()))

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=1)

print('ddf is')
print(ddf.head(10))

print('max Age from Dask Dataframe is')
print(str(ddf['Age'].max()))
```

**Result**

```
pandas_df is
     Name   Last Name  Age  Weight
0     Tom     Johnson   20    60.0
1  Joseph     Cameron   21    61.0
2   Krish       Biden   19    62.0
3    John  Washington   18    63.0
max Age from Pandas Dataframe is
21
ddf is
     Name   Last Name  Age  Weight
0     Tom     Johnson   20    60.0
1  Joseph     Cameron   21    61.0
2   Krish       Biden   19    62.0
3    John  Washington   18    63.0
max Age from Dask Dataframe is
dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int32>
```

Comment: read the tutorial - https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dataframe.html#Lazy-Evaluation

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.compute()` to make it an integer

```
print(ddf['Age'].max().compute())
```